# job for mongod.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process to dump core

Tags: mongodb, centos, redhat

I followed the steps mentioned in the link: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/ to install and start the mongodb server in CentOS 8 server. After completing the steps when i try to execute "sudo systemctl start mongod" command to start the mongodb server, I am getting the error mentioned in the below screenshot.

[error on executing "sudo systemctl start mongod" command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyseG.png)

Below is the screenshot of the stack trace when I execute "journalctl -xe".

[Stack trace on "journalctl -xe"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhByP.png)